# Restricted partition of integer: strictly k distinct parts from a set

Tags: combinatorics, integers, integer-partitions

I am looking for a way to compute/approach a serie of restricted partitions (or compositions) of integers.

I've found the $Q(n,k)$ quantity ([OEIS](http://oeis.org/A008289)) satisfying the first two of my following constraints :

- fixed order $k$
- $k$ distinct parts
- parts of the partition $\subset [1, \ldots, m]$

In other words, I would like to be able to count the number of the partitions (or directly the compositions) of an integer **n** in **k** distinct parts, the parts being taken from the set **[1, ..., m]**.

For an order of magnitude, my parameters would vary a lot, i.e. **n** would be pretty big, from a range between $200$ and $3000$, **k** between $5$ to $15$ and **m** between $60$ to $300$. My hope being that my strict contraints limit the numbering process.

I've looked through the OEIS website, MathWorld the work of Henry Bottomley  and tried the John d'Errico matlab code with no success until now so here I am.

If someone has an idea or any avenue to explore, I would be eternally grateful!

***Supplementary***

For example, on Matlab, at a first glance it seems to be able to get me what I want (with no consideration about the computation time) but when I'm running it it gives me partition with repetitive parts despite the max_count at 1.

I have also tried Wolfram, and it seemed very promising -as it was able to compute me very quickly some random "unrestricted" partition of big integer consistent with my parameters-

but despite the functions defined [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html), the

> *IntegerPartitions*[n,kspec,{s1,s2,…}]

is only running me the unrestricted partition

> *IntegerPartitions*[n]

in WolframAlpha.

---

**

### EDIT :

**

Great thanks N. Shales, really appreciated it!

You get my point and looking at the first coefficients, it seems to work smoothly but I have one doubt about something.

Accordingly to your example,

with $k=5$ and $m=10$

the minimum $n$ would be defined by $\frac{k^2+k}{2}$ as your generating function shows;

and then here would be 15, as the sum of the 5 first naturals from $[1,2,3,4,5, ...,10]$.

Reciprocally, the maximum $n$ would be 40 from $[1, ..., 6,7,8,9,10]$ and not 65 no?

I was defining this value by $$n_{max}=k \frac{2m-k+1}{2}$$

Moreover, when I am looking at $x^{40}$, the coefficient is 141 and I was expecting 1 -as for me there is only one way to achieve a maximal/minimal $n$ with strictly $k$ distinct parts from a set.

Am I missing something?

Last but not least, for clarity, do you mind to put your Sage code with the parameters?

Anyway, again thank you for your help, it is such a great way to learn here, thanks to people like you.

All the best!

**

### EDIT 2 :

**

New question about this.

When you are using this generating function proposed by N.Shales and getting the polynomial expression, by looking at the coefficients, you can observe an obvious symmetry.

Let's look at his example case for instance you have this serie
$$[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, ..., 19, 20, 20, 19, ..., 9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]$$
and when I'm looking at my cases I can make some very basic and intuitive observation based on the odd or even number of elements on those series and the two or one central integer with the biggest number of restricted partitions.

But I was wondering if you have a formal expression of this bell-curve looking like distribution?

Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, there was a small typo in my code (I had 16 instead of 11 for my exponent on $x$ in the numerator). Anyway, I've updated now and it's correct. The maximum $n$ is $10+9+8+7+6=40$ btw. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the "parameters", maybe you could elaborate with a comment (or perhaps you don't have the credit yet, I forget how much you need to comment). You can use that code exactly as it is if you click on the sage link, the code is pretty much wysiwyg. You are very kind and thanks for the lovely comments! :) Note: I use $x$ in sage as it is implicitly declared a variable.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that 39, my bad! Also about your code, you're right too. I was meaning a generic code with m and k and not example values but given the binomial coefficient it won't be more easy to get. At a first glance -and first time using sage, I was wondering about the last 1,5, now I get it -they are just referring to j=1 and k ... Thanks!

Comment: That's okay. Any more questions just comment. I think there is plenty of information at the sage website on how to get started using it so you should be alright there.

Comment: Yes thanks -and for the great course too. If you have some time I added a little supplementary question. Best!

Comment: You mean that you want some closed expression for the coefficients? I think the best I can do is a sum of complex numbers which is more complicated than using the generating function. If you mean an approximation, then that is currently outside my range of knowledge. You might like to ask that as a separate question, there may be someone here with more specialist knowledge than I. Sorry I couldn't be of any more help.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will do that then. Thank you anyway, you were of a great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [generating function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for distinct partitions into $k$ parts using elements from the set $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ is given using the [$q$-binomial coefficient](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient)

$$\binom{m}{k}_q=\prod_{j=1}^{k}\frac{1-q^{m+1-j}}{1-q^j}\, .$$

The desired generating function is simply:

$$q^{\binom{k+1}{2}}\binom{m}{k}_q=\sum_{n=\binom{k+1}{2}}^{\binom{k+1}{2}+mk}p_{n,k,m}^*q^n\, ,$$

where $p_{n,k,m}^*$ is the number of partitions of $n$ in to $k$ distinct parts with no part greater than $m$.

We can use, for example, the free open source computer algebra system [sage](http://sagecell.sagemath.org) to expand

$$q^{\binom{6}{2}}\binom{10}{5}_q $$

which lists, as it's coefficients, partitions into distinct parts with $k=5$ parts and no part greater than $m=10$. Using the sage input:

```
j=var('j')
f(x)=x^15*product((1-x^(11-j))/(1-x^j),j,1,5)
show(expand(f(x)))
```

we get output:

$$\begin{align}&x^{40} + x^{39} + 2 \, x^{38} + 3 \, x^{37} + 5 \, x^{36} + 7 \, x^{35} + 9 \, x^{34} + 11 \, x^{33} + 14 \, x^{32} + 16 \, x^{31} + 18 \, x^{30}\\& + 19 \, x^{29} + 20 \, x^{28} + 20 \, x^{27} + 19 \, x^{26} + 18 \, x^{25} + 16 \, x^{24} + 14 \, x^{23} + 11 \, x^{22} + 9 \, x^{21} +\\& 7 \, x^{20} + 5 \, x^{19} + 3 \, x^{18} + 2 \, x^{17} + x^{16} + x^{15}\end{align}$$

Here we have 1 such partition for each of 15 and 16, 2 such partitions of 17, 3 partitions of 18 and so on.

The `show` command allows us to retrieve the output in $\LaTeX$ format so that, for example, it can be used to illustrate an answer on MSE ;)

---

By the way: A [composition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) is different from a [partition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). For a composition the order of it's summands counts, whereas for partitions it doesn't.

Perhaps you already know this, however I am just making it clear for any other readers who may not be aware of the distinction. Of course, since we are counting partitions in to $k$ *distinct* parts then the number of compositions can be counted by multiplying by $k!$.

---

As per @GCab's request (see comments) I am posting a download link for more information on $q$-binomial coefficients:

[A Course in Enumeration by Martin Aigner (pdf download)](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~dahari/download/AdvancedInfi/Martin%2520Aigner%2520A%2520Course%2520in%2520Enumeration%2520%2520%25202007.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjU7IHa-djZAhXC-qQKHdWrDPwQFjAAegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw2k-7nlqXoJ-IW_Yvh5ttUy)

The relevant section is 1.6.

Aigner gives a lucid account of the connection between $q$-binomial coefficients, lattice paths and restricted partitions. He then goes on to link, via a well known bijection, to the restricted partitions into distinct parts (corollary 1.2) talked about here.

Comment: very nice and interesting, but could you elaborate or indicate a reference concerning how the ogf is achieved ?

Comment: @GCab, sure I'll see what else I can come up with. Did the link to q-binomial coefficients at the top not help at all?

Comment: yes, thanks, it contains also the combinatorial interpretation.

Comment: @GCab, I added an additional link at the bottom for further reading.

Comment: interesting paper indeed, with good introduction to Q-series, thanks